# Installer solution for WPF apps (with update/trial support)

Tags: wpf, installation

I have several WPF applications. And I think the number of apps would grow overtime. I want to create an installer with these features:

- Check for .Net version and ask the user to install it
- Support for creating a secure time-based trial version for the app with activation support.
- Template support: So I can create one general installer and modify it for each tool.
- Update support: Check for the new version of the app.
- Easy to deploy: There is a chance that I won't be uploading them myself.

If there is a tool which can help me with these, I'll be glad to use it. Commercial tools are fine too. If not, please suggest a streamlined process to achieve the optimal result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), [Enterprise edition](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/purchase.html), with a good price, has also all these features. To learn the tool I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html), after which you can continue with tutorials for the [updater](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-updater.html) and [licensing library(trial support)](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-licensing.html).

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it. Hopefully I can use this one.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield will do what you are looking for but it's not cheap. They have really nice wizards, script editors, SQL packaging, version control, etc.

[Flexera Software](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm)

Visual Studio 2010 / 2012 include the light version, but it can't really do more than wrap an app for installation. All the other advanced features are reserved to the paid versions.